# What happens when I return from inside a SQL cursor?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, return

I have the following code inside a cursor in a stored procedure I am working with:

```
SELECT @err_code = @@error

        If @err_code <> 0
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRAN
                Select return_status = 'FAIL',
                return_msg = 'Insert Into Errs Warnings Failed !!'
                return 16
            END
```

Before this error checking there is some table inserts (still inside the cursor). Recently I encountered an error where the table we were inserting into didn't match the insert statement that was coded (Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition). I would have thought that this error checking code would have caught this and killed the procedure, but for some reason all it did was print an error message to the log and continue running. `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition` was the error message.

So I'm wondering if this has to do with the return being inside of a cursor. Is is possible that in this scenario all the `return 16` would have done was exit the cursor and continue to execute the rest of the stored procedure? Or should it have terminated the procedure entirely? I'm using MS SQL Server 2008.

Thank you!

Comment: Two questions...why are you not using a TRY/CATCH block? And why are you using a cursor? This looks like a typical type of procedure where a cursor is not the best way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this @@ERROR function is , its scope is very limited. It will only be populated if an error occurs in the statement that was executed just before calling @@ERROR function.

If any other statement is executed before or called after that error occurred the @@ERROR will return NULL.

Also to anticipate where error may occur, and capture its value intime and stop the execution there, its a bit of a pain and error prone.

The best way of error handling in sql server would be try..catch block.

```
BEGIN TRY 

 BEGIN TRANSACTION 

 -- your code here 


 COMMIT TRANSACTION    --<-- this will only be executed if nothing 
                          -- goes wrong in prior statements
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 

  Select return_status = 'FAIL',
         return_msg = 'Insert Into Errs Warnings Failed !!'
END CATCH
```

Using Try...Catch block also gives you access to Error functions which can only be used in CATCH BLOCK and can help you to get detailed information about the error occurred in the Try..Block.

error functions like ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_LINE() , ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE() etc

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in a position to change this code right now, only figure out why the procedure did not terminate here. I forgot to mention that the code above does immediately follow the insert statement. My only question is: Would this return statement only exit the cursor and still run the rest of the procedure, or would it terminate the whole procedure even though it is inside a cursor?